# Getting nameof what an element references in a foreach

Tags: c#, arrays, string, foreach, nameof

I am trying to get the `nameof` a variable being passed through a `foreach` loop.

```
string[] printThis = {"doesntMatter"};
string[] andThis = {"doesntMatter"};
string[][] arrayOfArrays = {printThis, andThis};

foreach(string element in arrayOfArrays)
{
    string theNameOfTheElement = nameOf(element);
    Console.WriteLine(theNameOfTheElement + " ");
}
```

Instead of getting the desired result of

```
printThis andThis
```

I'm obviously getting just:

```
element
```

Is this not allowed? A better way?

Comment: The name of a variable does in no way follow the object it references, there is no way to backtrack from the reference in `element` back to the variable `printThis`. If you need to name your objects you should have objects that have a name property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nameof` operator is a lot simpler than you imply: it gives you the name of the variable/field/type/etc. that you pass to it as parameter. In your case that's an equivalent of `"element"` string.

There is no way to figure out the variable that was used to set a `string[][]` element, unless you save that information in a separate array or collection:

```
string[][] arrayOfArrays = {printThis, andThis};
string[] namesOfArrays =  {nameof(printThis), nameof(andThis)};
```

A better approach is to make a collection of name-array pairs:

```
var arrayOfArrays = {
    new {Name = nameof(printThis), Array=printThis}
,   new {Name = nameof(andThis), Array=andThis}
};
foreach (var p in arrayOfArrays) {
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    ...
}
```

Comment: A just make a duplicate, very clever.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to find the name of a variable from by value
With `nameof` you can get string name of Method, Property, Class, variable ... according to [nameof docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof)